# Serialize the map on every iteration

Tags: java, serialization

I have a ConcurrentHashMap which stores ID and timestamp when this ID was updated.
This data is to be persistent as application restart should be aware of the previous state of the data when shut-down was called. 
I am currently serializing the map to a file on shut-down and loading it back when the application restarts.

However I can foresee that the serialization on shutdown would fail when the disk is full. And this would mean data-loss which is unacceptable.
I thought of using a DB to store the data but then it would add network weight on every update.

The only thing that comes to my mind right now is to serialize the map on every update. This would ensure that most of the data is persistent in case of disk full also even in case of Unexpected shutdown.

I am aware that this is a heavy operation and am open for alternative solutions.

Also note, this map may hold over 1200K entries...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a (local) DB certainly seems better than serializing 1200k entries on each write.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a (local) database. DBs keep a transactional log to ensure there's no data loss even when something goes wrong. Serializing the map would be just trying to imitate that mechanism in a poor and broken way. Of course you'll have to change from using a concurrent map to a database, but that's probably just an improvement.

Comment: Instead of persisting the entire map on each update, why don't you just persist the updates?

Comment: Local DB is definitely the way to go (transaction log, automatic restore, etc). Additionally, a disk full error should never happen if you size & monitor your server correctly - eg. raising alerts when it reaches 90% for example

Comment: @thomas. This is a good idea.
I'll write the updates into a separate file and on shutdown flush these changes and delete this file. In case of unexpected shutdown the file will not be deleted and on restart i'll find the updates-file. So first will flush this file and then receive the newer changes.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario allowed some data loss then one solution can be

1.Periodically save snapshot of your hashmap so at most there will be a data loss for that interval.

2.For strict scenario you can log your action such that you can replay and get the original value.And as log is adding on end and read less may not be a performance hit.Log base technique used in like zookeper  for meta data storage.

3.Or you can persist to some kind of db asynchronously by using queue and process in batch.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. Kind of the solution i thought, but still it causes "some" data-loss which can be avoided.2. I like it better and it does makes sense to implement it that way. 3. A strict no as this would add maintenance on my part and also adds cases where db is not available...

Comment: Why a strict no to 3.? Except for the async part, you could use an internal db engine (a db that is part of your application as a jar file and starts up and shutdown with your app. Thus minimal-to-no maintenance, and recoverable state as well as atomic operations). Look at Derby, or maybe HSQL (Derby seems better)

Comment: My application is already using multiple tools. MySQL, Apache ActiveMQ, Apache Cassandra, Elasticsearch. Adding an in-memory db would surely add more maintenance on my part

Comment: Is it possible to simply just serialize the part of map that gets updated?

Comment: I did not get your question fully.How you will get the part map.if it some object then you can encoded to some json and put to some file

Comment: @HiteshHotchandani then why don't you use your mysql db? or for example, some kind of cache (that's what it looks like, your concurrentmap seems to be a cache) that will flush to disk? look at jcache or ehcache, or one of the many other cache providers